# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "beber los vientos"?

Tags: expresiones, historia

En el idioma español, el viento es origen y causa de multitud de expresiones. Hay una que me suele causar alguna que otra sonrisa:

> [beber alguien los aires por otra persona](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1L3KU50#ElddHgR)
>   [beber alguien los vientos por otra persona](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bnYP5E0#APkCQ8a)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Estar muy enamorado de ella.

La extrañeza de la expresión, dada por la imposibilidad de beberse un viento, me causa cierta hilaridad. Sin embargo, ¿de dónde viene la expresión? Al principio pensaba que "viento" se usaría con otro significado, hasta que vi que había una expresión similar que cambiaba el viento por aire. Así que mi teoría es que la expresión refleja que un enamorado haría cualquier cosa por su persona amada, hasta cosas imposibles como beberse un viento. Pero ¿quién se inventó la expresión? ¿Cuándo? ¿Dónde?

En [la Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beber_los_vientos) se mencionan un poema de 1775 y una obra de principios del siglo XVII que ya hace alusión al dicho como:

> dícese de un enamorado, bebe los vientos por fulano, y del que anda en pretensión que mucho desea

Sin embargo, en el CORDE se pueden encontrar usos más antiguos, aunque en sus acepciones de "[beber los vientos por algo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bnYP5E0)":

> *De todo lo susodicho parece cuánto convenga a la conciencia de S. M. confiarse en todo y por todo de los religiosos para descargar y cumplir con su real obligación, porque cierto es que mejor le ayudarán para este efecto los que otra cosa no pretenden ni en otra entienden, sino en descargar sus conciencias y las ajenas, que los que **beben los vientos** por cargar aun las suyas propias más que naos gruesas de mercaderías.*
>
> - Fray Jerónimo de Mendieta, "Carta del padre fray Jerónimo de Mendieta [Documentos para la Historia de México]", México (1562)

Y el ejemplo más antiguo que he encontrado, cuyo uso ya me causa más bien turbación:

> *Porque a todo esto contradice, primeramente, la naturaleza corrupta, amiga de sí misma; y contradice la flaqueza de nuestra humanidad; y contradice la inclinación de nuestro apetito, que es amigo de la cama blanda, de la vestidura preciosa y de la mesa delicada; de tal manera que por estas cosas trastorna el mundo, **bebe los vientos** y fatiga la mar.*
>
> - Fray Luis de Granada, "Libro de la oración y meditación", España (1554)

Si cambiamos vientos por aires, el caso más antiguo es el siguiente:

> *Santa es y grave la piedad cristiana, y su yugo según es muy ligero y muy suave a las almas que con él se reposan, así es grave y muy fatigoso a los que andan **bebiendo los aires** en vez de los placeres y deleites corporales.*
>
> *[...]*
>
> *Ahora, ¿qué diremos de aquellos otros hinchados en vano, que con una cierta soberbia callada y escondida andan **bebiendo los aires** por hacer subir a su hijo otro escalón y acrecentarle de estado, y aun (si ser pudiese) que de oficial se le armen caballero?*
>
> - Juan Justiniano, "Instrucción de la mujer cristiana, de J.L. Vives", España (1528)

Comment: Creo que en Wikipedia (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beber_los_vientos) tienes una respuesta al menos parcial.

Comment: @user amplío la pregunta incorporando esta información y otra basada en el CORDE.

Comment: me parece que se pudiera entender como suspiros profundos!

Answer (score 2):

> Parece ser que el origen de la metáfora "beber los vientos" procede, según Julio Cejador y Frauca en su Historia de la lengua y literatura castellana (1915), de los perros de caza venteadores, que, al olfatear el aire, parece como si lo estuvieran bebiendo.
>   Antiguamente se decía también "beber los vientos y los elementos", cosa ya un tanto más difícil de comprender, si la metáfora deriva del lenguaje venatorio. La cita más antigua es del maestro Gonzalo Correas en su obra Vocabulario de refranes y frases proverbiales y otras formas comunes de la lengua castellana, que es obra del primer tercio del siglo XVII y lo explica así: "beber los vientos y los elementos: dícese de un enamorado, bebe los vientos por fulano, y del que anda en pretensión que mucho desea".

Fuente: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beber_los_vientos